# How to ignore nulls in an Oracle analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle

This query :

```
select BILL_ID, BILL_DATE FROM BILLS
```

returns the following results:

```
bill_id----------bill_date

1943336232      12/03/15

null            null
```

with this sql :

```
select
FIRST_VALUE(BILL_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY BILL_DT DESC) bill_id,
FIRST_VALUE(BILL_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY BILL_DT DESC) bill_date
```

I get :

```
bill_id----------bill_date

null            null
```

What is the query that lets me get

```
bill_id----------bill_date

1943336232      12/03/15
```

?

I tried adding IGNORE NULLS but I always get both lines, please help thank you

PS : both line obviously have the same ACCOUNT_ID

Comment: How can a BILL_ID be NULL in a BILLS table?

Comment: GolezTrol, it is not, i simplified the query, it is a result of a left join

Comment: Oracle does support [ignore nulls](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions066.htm#SQLRF00642) clause.

Comment: I tried adding IGNORE NULLS but I always get both lines

Comment: I'm curious about your final query, because reading your specs, additions, comments and the accepted answer, I think you may have written a very complex inner join for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `NULLS LAST` option in your `ORDER BY` clause.

```
select
  FIRST_VALUE(BILL_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY BILL_DT DESC NULLS LAST) bill_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(BILL_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY BILL_DT DESC NULLS LAST) bill_date
...
```